# Is there a blender script to automatically apply a texture to a material from 'Open Image'? (Blender v2.71)

Tags: texturing, materials, image

I have an object with dozens of materials assigned, so in Edit Mode, having a material selected, I open an image from 'Open Image' to preview the texture, but doing that doesn't apply the texture to the material. So because of that I have to go to the 'Texture' panel, Add a new texture, set the 'Type' to 'Image or Movie' and apply the same texture for each material. Is there a script to do this automatically from opening the texture from 'Open Image'?